# How do I minimize a linear least squares function in R?

Tags: r, algorithm, least-squares

I'm reading *Deep Learning* by Goodfellow et al. and am trying to implement gradient descent as shown in Section 4.5 Example: Linear Least Squares. This is page 92 in the hard copy of the book.

The algorithm can be viewed in detail at https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/numerical.html with R implementation of linear least squares on page 94.

I've tried implementing in R, and the algorithm as implemented converges on a vector, but this vector does not seem to minimize the least squares function as required. Adding epsilon to the vector in question frequently produces a "minimum" less than the minimum outputted by my program.

```
options(digits = 15)
dim_square = 2 ### set dimension of square matrix
# Generate random vector, random matrix, and 
set.seed(1234) 
A = matrix(nrow = dim_square, ncol = dim_square, byrow = T, rlnorm(dim_square ^ 2)/10)
b = rep(rnorm(1), dim_square)

# having fixed A & B, select X randomly 
x = rnorm(dim_square) # vector length of dim_square--supposed to be arbitrary

f = function(x, A, b){
  total_vector = A %*% x + b # this is the function that we want to minimize
  total = 0.5 * sum(abs(total_vector) ^ 2) # L2 norm squared
  return(total)
}
f(x,A,b)

# how close do we want to get?
epsilon = 0.1
delta = 0.01

value = (t(A) %*% A) %*% x - t(A) %*% b
L2_norm = (sum(abs(value) ^ 2)) ^ 0.5

steps = vector()
while(L2_norm > delta){
  x = x - epsilon * value
  value = (t(A) %*% A) %*% x - t(A) %*% b
  L2_norm = (sum(abs(value) ^ 2)) ^ 0.5
  print(L2_norm)
}

minimum = f(x, A, b)
minimum

minimum_minus = f(x - 0.5*epsilon, A, b)
minimum_minus # less than the minimum found by gradient descent! Why?
```

On page 94 of the pdf appearing at https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/numerical.html

I am trying to find the values of the vector x such that f(x) is minimized. However, as demonstrated by the minimum in my code, and minimum_minus, minimum is *not* the actual minimum, as it exceeds minimum minus.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: The first link should read:  https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/numerical.html

Comment: you can edit your question to change the link

Answer (score 0):

[Original Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ymsr.png)

Finding the value of x such that the quantity Ax - b is minimized is equivalent to finding the value of x such that Ax - b = 0, or x = (A^-1)*b. This is because the L2 norm is the euclidean norm, more commonly known as the distance formula. By definition, distance cannot be negative, making its minimum identically zero.

This algorithm, as implemented, actually comes quite close to estimating x. However, because of recursive subtraction and rounding one quickly runs into the problem of underflow, resulting in massive oscillation, below:

[Value of L2 Norm as a function of step size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rbwqt.png)

[Above algorithm vs. *solve* function in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4olR.png)

Above we have the results of A %*% x followed by A %*% min_x, with x estimated by the implemented algorithm and min_x estimated by the *solve* function in R.

The problem of underflow, well known to those familiar with numerical analysis, is probably best tackled by the programmers of lower-level libraries best equipped to tackle it.

To summarize, the algorithm appears to work as implemented. Important to note, however, is that not every function will have a minimum (think of a straight line), and also be aware that this algorithm should only be able to find a local, as opposed to a global minimum.